# Rewriting URLs with .htaccess and mod_rewrite causes server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm writing a website and I have a php file in the home directory that will grab the GET variables in the query string and open a video based on the query string id. The query string is: http://www.viewingtree.com/playlists.php?id=5914242 . I want to make that string look like http://www.viewingtree.com/playlists/5914242 . I'm using a .htaccess file on an Apache server with mod_rewrite installed, so I have this as my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^playlists/([0-9]+) /playlists.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

When I enter the URL with the query string, the web page loads as it should. However, when I use the SEO-friendly URL, the page still loads but without any of the CSS formatting that I used. Is my .htaccess incorrect, or what?

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for concrete information on what went wrong. The RewriteRule seems okay.

Comment: What does the error log say? Is the rewrite library loaded?

Comment: Could be as simple as the server's config not allowing rewrites or php_value directives in  .htaccess (too restrictive AllowOverride option).

Comment: Getting rid of php_value options in .htaccess made the mod_rewrite work, but now the CSS formatting is lost when using the rewritten URL over the query string URL.

Comment: You can use absolute URLs or `<base href=>` in your html documents.

Comment: <base href=" "> fixed the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using **absolute URLs** for CSS and JavaScript.  The relative URL is causing this issue.

Try something like:

```
<link media="screen" href="/style/defaultTheme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" href="/style/tablethemes.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Using absolute urls, or <base href="url" />, worked to fix my issue. Thanks!